# Creating Hyperlink in Dynamically Created Table error 'Table' cannot have children of type 'HyperLink'.

Tags: c#, hyperlink, dynamic-data

I am trying to create a hyperlink in a table cell, this is what I have so far.

I error out with this message, "'Table' cannot have children of type 'HyperLink'."

How can I fix this?

```
    TableRow Label11 = new TableRow();
    TableCell Label11TC = new TableCell();
    HyperLink P30HL = new HyperLink();
    P30HL.NavigateUrl = "http://endor/RequestIT/Remee/test/Details.aspx";
    P30HL.Text = (work / dda).ToString("p");
    Label11.Cells.Add(Label11TC);
    Table1.Controls.Add(P30HL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the hyperlink into a table cell instead of the table...

```
TableRow Label11 = new TableRow();
TableCell Label11TC = new TableCell();
HyperLink P30HL = new HyperLink();
P30HL.NavigateUrl = "http://endor/RequestIT/Remee/test/Details.aspx";
P30HL.Text = (work / dda).ToString("p");
Label11.Cells.Add(Label11TC);
Label11TC.Controls.Add(P30HL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there Justin Harvey, just some syntax related errors....add the hyperlink to a cell, then add the cell to a row, then add the row to the table.

```
 TableRow tbRow= new TableRow();
 TableCell tbCell = new TableCell();

 HyperLink hyplnk= new HyperLink();
 hyplnk.NavigateUrl = "http://endor/RequestIT/Remee/test/Details.aspx";
 hyplnk.Text = (work / dda).ToString("p");

 tbCell.Controls.Add(hplink);
 tbRow.Controls.Add(tbCell);

 TableID.Controls.Add(tbRow); //TabledID is the ID you give the table in the ASPX page
```

The above worked for me